# dropdown with backgrounds as option show selected

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have dropdown with different background as option like red, blue and green.

I want that when someone selects the green color it will be green and like so. How can I do this?

Below is my html code:

```html
<select name="mcolor" class="form-control" id="mcolor">
  <option value="">-- select color --</option>                             <option value="#ff0000" style="background-color:#ff0000">&nbsp;</option>      
  <option value="#ffffff" style="background-color:#ffffff">&nbsp;</option>              </select>
```

Comment: use onchange event JS and in JS add selected bgcolor to where you want. Means implementing a JS function and adding selected bgcolor. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521565/html-select-with-different-background-color-for-every-option-that-works-properly.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/LnMsw/368/

Answer (score 1):

This is how to change the background color on select:

```
$("#mcolor").change(function(){
    $('body').css("background-color", $(this).val());
});
```

**[JSFiddle demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/ws47uy98/)**

Answer (score 0):

```js
function colourFunction() {
var myselect = document.getElementById("select1"),
colour = myselect.options[myselect.selectedIndex].className;
myselect.className = colour;
myselect.blur(); 
}
```

```css
#select1 {width:150px; color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);}
#select1:focus, #select1:focus {
color:black;
}
.white {background:white;}
.red {background:red;}
.yellow {background:yellow;}
.green {background:green}
```

```html
<select id="select1" onchange="colourFunction()">
<option class="white" value="A">This should have a WHITE background</option>
<option class="red" value="B">This should have a RED background</option>
<option class="yellow" value="C">This should have a YELLOW background</option>
<option class="green" value="D">This should have a GREEN background</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Here I'm giving only to select.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
    $('.form-control').on('change', function() {
      $(this).css('background-color', $(this).val());
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="mcolor" class="form-control" id="mcolor">
        <option value="red">-- red --</option>  
        <option value="green">-- green --</option>  
        <option value="black">-- black --</option>  
        </select>
```