# Angular - dropdown menu background color

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have this code in `html` using `Angular`:

```
<select name="singleSelect" ng-model="priority.APME" style="width:100%;" ng-change="changedValue(priority.APME,$index,priority)" >
            <option value="" selected>Main Elements</option>
            <option ng-repeat="me in mainelements" value="{{$index}}" ng-disabled="me.optiondisable == true">{{me.Title}}</option>
          </select>
```

Now my client want to put different color for different options dynamically(option1 is green, option2 is red,...).

I googled and test with some code:

```
<option ng-repeat="me in main elements" style="background: #5456e3 !important;" value="{{$index}}" ng-disabled="me.optiondisable == true">{{me.Title}}</option>
```

and

```
<option ng-repeat="me in main elements" style="background-color: #5456e3 !important;" value="{{$index}}" ng-disabled="me.optiondisable == true">{{me.Title}}</option>
```

Both of the above not working. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You want the `<select>` tag, to change its background color depending on the selected option?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521565/html-select-with-different-background-color-for-every-option-that-works-properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to assign a color property to incoming array, then use `ng-style` to bind that color to the option.

```
<select>
   <option value="" selected>Main Elements
   </option>
   <option ng-repeat="me in mainelements"
           ng-style ="{'background-color': me.Color}">{{me.Title}}
   </option>
</select>
```

[Working Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/fGNKTvDEDLtk92kHXGbn?p=preview)

Comment: I tested this and it only works with `Firefox` but not in `Chrome` and `Safari`. Is there something else I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: The plunker works for me in firefox and chrome. I dont have safari to test it, but it should work fine there as well. See console for more.

Comment: Is it because I am using Mac?

Answer (score 1):

There can be many ways, I would recommend that you specify a `color` attribute in the data itself and then set the background color according to that data.

[see this Plunker I've created for the exact solution](http://plnkr.co/edit/OSIM3Vg78FRPWSvPcasv?p=preview)

```js
angular.module('plunker', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.fruits = [
    {name: 'Apple', color: '#5bb75b'},
    {name: 'Banana', color: '#08c'},
    {name: 'Cherry', color: 'yellow'},
  ];
  
  $scope.setBgColor = function() {
    $("#selectedFruit").css("background-color", JSON.parse($scope.selectedFruit).color);
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.7/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.0.7"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <select id="selectedFruit" ng-model="selectedFruit" style="background-color:{{JSON.parse($scope.selectedFruit).color}}" ng-change="setBgColor()">
    <option ng-repeat="sdata in fruits" style="background-color:{{sdata.color}}" value="{{sdata}}">{{sdata.name}}</option>
  </select>
</body>

</html>
```